# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS doesn't recognize my password

Tags: 18.04, password

I have just bought a new OEM sets. In it is 8700K processor and Z390 Gaming Plus board with Asus GTX1060 6GB graphic card. When I install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, after finishing installing and reboot it will load and then next it will appear user "name" then asking for password. I key in my password but it will say it is not recognized and keep asking for my password. And I cannot use it.

Appreciate if anyone can help to solve the problem cos I have tried reinstalling the OS but still the same problem exist.

---

I install using a bootable USB Drive with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS in it. I have installed on my Dell XPS M1330 and OEM desktop without any problem and working fine. But both laptop and desktop is with integrated graphic. Unlike this one with a external graphic card. Do I need to note special installations instructions when it come to system with external graphic card?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What did you use to install Ubuntu?

Preferably use this guide:

https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver

Then, there are two passwords:

1. (Optional) Password to encrypt the device(Security Key)

This one is only to decrypt your device(Only if you selected encryption while installing)

2. User Password to login

This Password is given after selecting a user name. You will need THIS password to sign in.

Optionally try installing Ubuntu and checking the `Log in automatically` box. Then no password would be required to sign in.